# My laptop battery just won't come out! (Lenovo U400)

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

I'm trying to remove the battery from a Lenovo U400 laptop. It should be as easy as taking out the screws from the battery, unplugging it from the motherboard, and lifting it out, but it's not!

Once I try to unplug the battery connector from its port, it won't budge, not even a little bit. Here's a video for reference on what I'm trying to do: Youtube video: http://youtu.be/F6BTC9heZrA?t=34s.

I tried pulling with as much force as I reasonably could without breaking anything, and the connector just won't move. Is there something I'm missing? The video makes it look so easy!

Here's a picture of the what the connector I'm working with looks like: [image: Lenovo U400 battery connector]

And here's a rather more artistic rendering: [image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried applying slight force to push the connector *in*, then push down with a spudger (as shown in the video), then try to remove the connector? I'm thinking that maybe there is a slight lip somewhere inside which defeats the initial pushing with a spudger.

Comment: This may sound strange, but I would put the laptop in a plastic bag (make sure its properly sealed) and place it in the fridge for an hour so it cools down. This may cause the components to shrink a little making it easier to pull the cable out.

Comment: You have the same model in the video right?